# Can autoincrement in mysql increment by 2?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

Is there any way to set autoincrement in mysql(I'm using phpmyadmin) so that it increments by 2 ?

The reason I want it to do so is that I have 2 tables but need the id of each to be different. So table 1 would go 1, 3,5,...... and table2 would be 2, 4, 6......

Thank you

Comment: ...as an alternative you could keep the default ID behaviour of the database and calculate the required ids i.e. for Table 1, newId = (2 * Id), for Table 2, newId = (2 * Id) + 1. Obviously depends on why you need these Ids to be different

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can it with this:

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The MS SQL Server uses the IDENTITY keyword to perform an auto-increment feature.

By default, the starting value for IDENTITY is 1, and it will increment by 1 for each new record.

To specify that the column should start at value 10 and increment by 2, change the identity to IDENTITY(10,2).